# How to efficienlty calculate the difference between array items and find out how many differences are less than a certain value?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

I have an array and need to calculate the difference between each item and all the other items. If the difference is less than or equal to a certain value (limit), I have to count that as 1.

I implemented it using the brute force method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < n) {

        if (Math.abs(arr1[i] - arr1[j]) <= limit) {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm searching for optimized solution, as the time complexity here is `O(n^2)`. What would be a good solution to this problem if I want to avoid 2 loops?

Comment: But then it would not go through comparing each element in the array. If I remove the while loop, the j will not go through all elements.

Comment: "calculate the difference between each item" what does this mean ? between every item and all other items ?

Comment: Yes. Between every item and all other items.

Comment: So  when `i=0` no other element are tested ?  And when `i=j` you are testing an element against itself.

Comment: you also compare pairs of elements twice - this sounds inefficient

Answer (score 4):

If you have to determine whether the difference between each pair of elements in the array <= limit, it would be beneficial to sort the array (O(NlogN)) first.

Now, for each element x in the sorted array, you have to find the length of the range of elements having value between x - limit and x + limit. This can be found using binary search (i.e. call `Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, x - limit)` and `Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, x + limit)`) in `O(logN)` time. You add the length of that range to the total sum.

Since you have to repeat that action for each element, the total time would be O(NlogN).

Finally, since you will count each pair twice, you have to divide the result by two.

The total running time will be `O(NlogN) + O(NlogN) = O(NlogN)`.

BTW, your current implementation seems incorrect:

1. You are comparing each element against itself, which will have extra value of n to the total sum.
2. You are comparing each pair of elements twice, so each pair which is close enough will be counted twice.

EDIT: Actually, since instead of counting each close pair twice and then dividing by two, we can count the pairs just once if we only count the number of elements between `array[i]` (exclusive) and `array[i] + limit` (inclusive). This means it's enough to run the binary search once for each index.

Here's a running example:

```
public static int comparePairs (int[] arr1, int limit) {
    int sum = 0;
    Arrays.sort (arr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {
        int last = Arrays.binarySearch (arr1, arr1[i] + limit);
        if (last > 0) {
          sum += last - i;
        } else {
          sum += -last - i - 2;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that it does not support duplicate elements, so it willl require some adjustments to work with duplicates.

For example, it returns `9` for the array `{2,6,4,3,1,5}` and the limit `2` (the pairs being (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (2,4) (3,4) (3,5) (4,5) (4,6) (5,6)).

Comment: I tested with following input {1,3,4,5,7,9}. I get as answer 12. I would have expected 8: (1,3) (1,4) (3,4) (3,5) (4,5) (4,7) (5,7) (7,9). I like your solution but I believe there is a bug, or I overlooked something.

Comment: Forgot to mention limit = 3

Comment: @aldert thanks, I'll check it when I can. Yes, I must be misprocessing the values returned by binarySearch in some of the cases.

Comment: @Aldert I believe I fixed it. I even simplified the logic. thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: Every time you increment `i`, you should increment `last` to the proper value instead of doing a binary search.  It's simpler and faster -- since it can only increase, the total time for finding last becomse O(N) instead of O(N log N)